# Photon encoding and computational limit of the universe

Tags: quantum-information, entropy

The amount of information or entropy that can be contained in a region of space is given by the Bekenstein Bound:

$I \leq \frac{2\pi RE} {hc \ln2}$

However, recent publications have shown information encoding in multiple dimensions, up to 10 dimensions on a single photon([Kues et al.](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature22986))

What is the relationship between photon encoding in multiple dimensions and the Bekenstein Bound? And more broadly, the computational limitations of our universe?

Comment: I know nothing about Bekenstein bound, but not that the "multiple dimensions" of the experiment you are referring to are not *spatial* dimensions. Using the same definition of "dimension", a single photon is in general *infinite*-dimensional, as it it characterised by continuous degrees of freedom such as the spatial profile of its wavefunction.

Comment: I suppose I should have clarified, I am aware that photon encoding is obviously not in spatial dimensions(otherwise string theorists would have went crazy), a big part of what I want to know is what effect these results(if any) have on the computation limits of the universe which is usually cited at about $10^{120}$ operations if we consumed all mass-energy with perfect efficiency and proportional storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this [link](https://www.scottaaronson.com/democritus/lec14.html) will be useful, particularly when he begins discussing the 5th argument. The answer as to why quantum computing doesn't violate the Bekenstein Bound is that if we have $n$ two dimensional entangled quantum systems, qubits, (the argument works similarly with 10 dimensional systems, except we work with a base of 10 instead of 2) there is a theorem, the [Holevo Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holevo%27s_theorem) which gives the amount of reliable classical bits that can be recovered from the system, namely $n$ classical bits. The system requires $2^n$ complex variables to describe, so given an $n$ sufficiently large, we could certainly make it look like we are violating the Bekenstein Bound, e.g. by having a system which requires $2^{10000}$ continuous complex variables to completely specify, but we couldn't "cash the system out". That is we couldn't recover even a minuscule fraction of that information from the system. Thus when we consider the number of classical bits stored in a quantum system, it still only scales linearly with the number of quantum bits, and thus we can't violate the Bekenstein Bound.

Comment: Hmmm, you mention that classical and quantum information storage will scale linearly(if I am not taking you out of context to harshly). However, Freeman Dyson made an argument, in a discussion with Krauss on "can life exist forever"(https://goo.gl/Ab5hVg), that the amount of information you can store in the classical phase space is $N \log L$ vs quantum $N$

Comment: Can you give a specific time in the video and/or give what $L$ is.

Comment: I would watch the whole thing;) but 28:50 abouts

Comment: What he's talking about in his talk involved a classical system with variable volume. Usually when we consider a classical system with $n$ bits we are considering other things to be constant. Plus the whole $\log L$ thing isn't really pertinent to the Bekenstein bound issue which really only is an issue if you were able to recover all the quantum amplitudes of a quantum system, as the number of such amplitude grows with $2^n$, $n$ being the number of qubits.